# Stream and capture HLS with FFMpeg in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

I am using this command to capture an HLS stream with FFMpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i some_m3u8_link -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc video.mp4
```

Is there any way to actually see what I am capturing in real time? Perhaps with *ffplay*?

This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689505/capturing-and-streaming-with-ffmpeg-while-displaying-locally), except I need to be able to do this in CMD on Windows specifically. Also the other question is 11 months old and did not get an answer.

Comment: Do you have any example of that m3u8 file that you/all human beings are allowed to download by "the law"?

Comment: Not sure how that helps. The input could be anything. But no, unfortunately I cannot share the source of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe a 2nd output to ffplay.

```
ffmpeg -i some_m3u8_link -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc video.mp4 -c copy -f mpegts - | ffplay -f mpegts -
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why should I use the mpegts demuxer specifically?

Comment: No global header, so codec parameters are available with first packet. For MP4s, they are only written after packets are muxed.